# Alias mock persists over test classes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, phpunit, mockery

I have created an alias mock using [Mockery](http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/index.html) in class A to mock calls to some public static methods that are made in the class I want to test.

In a different test class B I want to use these public static methods (not mocked) but it seems like the alias mock created in test class A persists when test class B is executed. When running the tests in test class B I get this exception: `BadMethodCallException: Static method Helper::formatDate() does not exist on this mock object`, even though the Helper class should not be mocked in class B.

I have tried to add:

```
/**
 * @runTestsInSeparateProcesses
 * @preserveGlobalState disabled
 */
```

in the test classes to make them run separately, but then I get this error:

`PHPUnit_Framework_Exception: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'TestCase' not found`

Anyone that has any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Try using AspectMock, that is supposed to mock static methods: https://github.com/Codeception/AspectMock

Anyway this problem is an indication of your code not being testable. You should consider refactoring it and not using static calls that need to be mocked.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @gontrollez. With Mockery it's also possible to mock static methods, and I don't really want to change mocking framework as I have quite a lot of unit tests already that uses Mockery. Mockery is also integrated into the framework I am using. I might be able to refactor my code but Laravel is using quite a lot of static method calls by default.

Comment: Yup, I get it. I haven't used Laravel in real projects so I can't tell, but I'm pretty sure that there must be a way to fully test code developed with Laravel. Try asking a Laravel-related question on this.